# installing node-gd in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, gd, node-gyp

when I install node-gd lib, I'm getting the following warning:

```
root@iZ25mlpjokyZ:~# npm install node-gd
/
> node-gd@1.1.0 install /root/node_modules/node-gd
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/4.3.1"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/root/node_modules/node-gd/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/node_modules/node-gd/.node-gyp/4.3.1"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/root/node_modules/node-gd/.node-gyp"
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to build this as root. Besides, it's best to install it in a project folder, but you're trying to install it in root's home directory which is strongly discouraged.

Comment: thanks, I will take your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks.
I solved it with the following commands:

```
apt-get install g++ gcc
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

the package on website tells us to install libgd2-dev using ubuntu package manager as

```
sudo apt-get install libgd2-dev
```

but this package is not available in the source list the thing that worked for me is as follows

```
sudo apt-get isntall libgd-dev 
npm i node-gd --save
```